# vba code gives me run time error 91 object variable or with block not set

Tags: excel, vba

Would you please help me why there is `91` code error in the below. I would appreciate a lot.

```
  Dim ra As Range
  Dim length As Integer

Set ra = Range("AE:AE").Find(What:="Dell EMC Maintenance Representative", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)
    length = Len(ra)

If length < 40 Then
    MsgBox ("Sales Rep. is missing!")
    GoTo BEG

    Else
```

GoTo BEG

Thanks alot

Comment: Please format your code properly and make sure it is all inside code tags.

Comment: Your `FIND` isn't finding anything so `ra Is Nothing` when you try and get the `LEN` of it which returns the error.  After searching for the value check `IF NOT ra IS NOTHING THEN....` before continuing.  If it should be finding something check that both strings exactly match - no extra spaces, hidden characters?

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs when you try to perform the `len()` operation on your `ra` range object. When you set `ra` you must consider the case when the `.Find` method doesn't find your search criteria. When this happens, the `ra` object holds nothing and you cannot perform the `len()` operation on `nothing`.

You should trap for this by checking to make sure `ra` got set to something before trying to check the length. Like this:

```
If ra Is Not Nothing Then
    length = Len(ra)
Else
    'handle this case (length = 0)
End If
```

Comment: Also note that `Range("AE:AE").Find(....` searches the `ActiveSheet`  Might be worth adding `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AE:AE").Find(....`